# How can I insert special characters in SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to insert the word 'at' in a `SimpleDateFormat` so a date would look like:

> Wed, 26 May 2010 at 11:17am

I'm able to make it appear without the at, like this

> Wed, 26 May 2010 11:17am

by using

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mma");
```

How can I insert the word "at"?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can escape literals using single quotes.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy 'at' hh:mma");
```

This will output Wed, 26 May 2010 at 11:17am