# How to display time in HHhMM a format in java ?

Tags: java, datetime, hour

I want to display time in HHhMM format. For example if time is 09:30 AM i want to display it as 9h45 AM . I tried below approach :-

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class PS6 {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Date dNow = new Date( );
      SimpleDateFormat ft = 
      new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' HHhMM a");

      System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));
   }
}
```

But Th e output was

```
Current Date: Fri 2016.10.21 at 14210 PM
```

which is incorrect.

Can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: What's the correct String you want to see? What's the small h in `HHhMM` format?

Comment: did you try to use escaping `new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' HH'h'MM a");`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert special characters in SimpleDateFormat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912149/how-can-i-insert-special-characters-in-simpledateformat)

Comment: You quoted the `'at'` because it's to be taken literally, you also need to quote the `'h'` as it is also literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
Date dNow = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' HH'h'MM a");
System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use this one `SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' H'h'MM a");` you will get Current Date: Fr 2016.10.21 at 8h10 AM. I think this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to other answers given so far, you should also know that M stands for the month, not for the minute, and H stands for the 24-hour-clock which is questionable in context of having am/pm-marker. It is also worth to explicitly specify a locale.

So please use this pattern instead:

```
Date dNow = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh'h'mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(
    "Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow)); // Current Date: Fri 2016.10.21 at 12h32 PM
```