# "h" as text in DateFormat in Java

Tags: java, android

I have a DateFormat

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat HOUR_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("HHh", Locale.US);
```

I want to display date as `05h` but Formatter recognize `h` as hour(0-12). 
How to pass `h` as text?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2912173/5280641

Comment: [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is quite expressive. Everything is explained and some case have examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code snippet:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat HOUR_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("HH'h'", Locale.US);
```

Comment: Nice! It works!

Answer (score 1):

You can insert special caracters by using simple quotes 'h'.
Be careful with your SimpleDateFormat as it is not thread safe.